# Translate from English to first-order logic: There is somebody who likes everyone who likes John

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, logic-translation

Translate from English to first-order logic: There is somebody who likes everyone who likes John

I'm not sure about the answer. What I'm thinking is $(∃x)(L(x,y)∧L(x,J))$

Comment: I'm assuming $L(x,y)$ means $x$ likes $y$.

Reading your thought to myself, I read: "There is somebody ($x$) who likes $y$ and who likes $J$."

Answer (score 2):

$$(\exists x)(\forall y)(L(y,J)\rightarrow L(x,y))$$

Translation:

There exists $x$ such that if $y$ likes John, then $x$ likes $y$.

Comment: Don't you mean $(\exists x)(\forall y)(L(y,J)\to L(x,y))$? The way you wrote it, $y$ is a free variable.

Comment: I guess I assumed that an unquantified variable not specified as constant was automatically quantfified, by default, with "for all". But I'll edit my answer to make that explicit. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the default be $(\forall y)(\exists x)(L(y,J)\to L(x,y))$?

Comment: I guess so, so the edit was _necessary_, else the default order would yield the wrong meaning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The English language is not logically precise, so the sentence has two (possible more) interpretations. The first, as given by @quasi, is "there is somebody who likes (everybody who likes John)", and has the translation $(\exists x)(\forall y)(L(y,J)\rightarrow L(x,y))$. The second is "there is (somebody who likes everybody) who likes John", which has the translation $(\exists x)[(\forall y(L(x,y)))\,\land\,L(x,J)]$. Here $L(a,b)$ means $a$ likes $b$.

(The first is probably the intended meaning, because if somebody liked everyone, they would surely like John. I'm just pointing out an interpretation closer to what you were originally thinking.)

Comment: Thank you. The second answer is what I originally thinking. I was not sure how to translate it correctly. I agree with you that the first translation might be the intended meaning.

Comment: @Haley_Q You're welcome! If you like my answer, please upvote it (the up arrow) and accept it if it answers your question.

Comment: For the first interpretation, do you really want $y$ to be a free variable, or did you miss out a $\forall y$?

Comment: @bof Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There is some person who likes everyone who likes John. So, there is some person $x$ who likes all people $y$ who satisfy the condition that $y$ likes John.  So, there exists a person $x$ such that for all $y$, if $y$ likes John then $x$ likes $y$. We have the expression: $\exists x, \forall y (L(y,J) \implies L(x,y))$.